# Microsoft Azure login success returns empty scopes - react-native-app-auth - Getting 401

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

While I try to make an custome backend API call with the accessToken I receive from login success using [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth), the call fails and returns a 401 error.

My login succeeds with no error but the response I get after login, consists of empty scopes `scopes: []`

Below is my config,

```
const AuthorizationConfig = {
  appId: 'XXXXX',
  tenantId: 'XXXX',
  appScopes: [
    'openid',
    'offline_access',
    'profile',
    'User.Read',
    'api://XXXX/access_as_user',
  ],
};

export const config: any = {
  warmAndPrefetchChrome: true,
  clientId: AuthorizationConfig.appId,
  redirectUrl: 'com.dcomobile://react-native-auth/',
  scopes: AuthorizationConfig.appScopes,
  additionalParameters: {prompt: 'select_account'},
  serviceConfiguration: {
    authorizationEndpoint:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' +
      AuthorizationConfig.tenantId +
      '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' +
      AuthorizationConfig.tenantId +
      '/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  },
};
```

I call this function to authorize which in turn opens a Microsoft Login window in a mobile browser

```
const result = await authorize(config);
```

`result.accessToken` contains the token which I have to append to the header section in my API call. The token is a `Bearer` token

I'm wondering if my scopes are wrong as it as scopes for both MSGraph and custom API.

Any leads would be helpful! TIA

Comment: Hi @gem1234 , can you please provide more information about error?

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi-MT Hi, im just simply catching that in a .catch block and it says
Error: Request failed with status code 401